# what method docker use to give container an ip address?

Tags: docker

how a container get its eth0 IP address.

I didn't find in the docker documentation

```
sudo rgrep  172.17.0.2 / return nothing
```

Is it by dhcp ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could only find some older code references that explain a little bit how this works: https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/ded74b0bb37d328a8c1a69f1f9b9aca2bba58199/network.go#L417-L479. Obviously, with overlay networks and changes since, there could be other ways containers get IP addresses. But I believe the default below still applies.

The daemon sets the bridge interface that containers will get IP addresses from. By default, a bridge called `docker0` will be created. It will use network `172.17.42.1/16` or other networks if that overlaps with a local host network.

Inside this Docker bridge, Docker will attempt to assign an address sequentially and move on to the next if not available.

Comment: ok but why there is no reference to the ip address in the container ?

Answer (score 0):

@andy-shinn's answer is correct for docker 1.9.1 and below; docker 1.10 will allow you to specify a custom IP-address for a container for each network it's connected to.

(Note that this feature is only supported for custom networks, and only if a subnet is specified)

For example;

```
docker network create -d bridge --subnet 172.25.0.0/16 mynet

docker run -itd --net=mynet --ip=172.25.3.3 alpine sh
```

For more information see the [pull request](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/19286/files)